# How to use Geofence in my Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, geofencing

I need to implement a geofence in a perticular location that get location from xamarin.essential's location. I have tried [this](https://github.com/aritchie/geofences) xamarin.essential plugin but seems like it has moved and no clear documentation.

Comment: http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#geolocation\

Comment: @AndroDevil there is no geofencing right. As I see there is only geolocation.

Comment: @Argon Do you have a try with this sample ? https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/Location/Geofencing/

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT It's about Xamarin.Android. But i'm looking for Xamarin.Forms implementation. BTW thanks for the ref